# Can't access office365 Calendar API

Tags: azure, outlook, oauth-2.0, office365, outlook-restapi

I want to get an access to Calendar rest API from my Ruby application.
I've created azure multi-tenant app, and configured it.

I'm trying to get an access token to resource "https://outlook.office365com/", but I get an error

```
'AADSTS50001: Resource 'https://outlook.office365.com/' is disabled.'
```

I can't find any description of this error, and can't understand why it's disabled

---

Here are my azure app permissions:

[image]

Comment: Want to make sure you're trying to access "https://outlook.office365.com/" and not "https://outlook.office365com" first off. If that's right, I'm curious if you are still hitting this error. I just made a call to the endpoint without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

That's a new error for me! Let's check if the Exchange principals are disabled. To do that you'll need to use Remote Powershell to connect to the Azure AD service.

Here's how to do it (I'm assuming you have Powershell installed on a Windows machine):

1. Install the Azure AD module for Powershell: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj151815.aspx#bkmk_installmodule
2. Open the "Windows Azure Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell". Follow the steps under "Connect to Azure AD" in the linked article.
3. Run the following command: `Get-MsolServicePrincipal -AppPrincipalId 00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000`

You should see output like this:

```
ExtensionData         : System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject
AccountEnabled        : True
Addresses             : {}
AppPrincipalId        : 00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000
DisplayName           : Microsoft.Exchange
ObjectId              : f7d177d5-2071-45a9-b494-9b98cb4d80e3
ServicePrincipalNames : {00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000/outlook.office365
                        .com, 00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000/mail.office3
                        65.com,
                        00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000/outlook.com,
                        00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000/*.outlook.com...}
TrustedForDelegation  : True
```

Can you run the command and post your results?

Comment: it differs in `AccountEnabled        : False`

Comment: Ok. It sounds like your subscription to Exchange Online isn't active. Can you log into Outlook Web App at https://outlook.office365.com with the user that you're trying to login to your Ruby app with?

Comment: Thanks, you were right about inactive Exchange subscription. Now I got a good token, I can parse it on 'http://jwt.calebb.net/', but when I'm trying to get any resource, I get 401 error: `"x-ms-diagnostics"=>"2000001;reason=\"No applicable user context claims found.\";error_category=\"invalid_token\""`

Comment: Can you post your parsed token (you can remove your tenant ID and other identifying info, I just want to see the structure)? Which resource are you trying to access?

Comment: `{
 typ: "JWT",
 alg: "RS256",
 x5t: "***",
 kid: "***"
}.
{
 aud: "https://outlook.office365.com",
 iss: "https://sts.windows.net/***/",
 iat: 1435974355,
 nbf: 1435974355,
 exp: 1435978255,
 ver: "1.0",
 tid: "***",
 email: "admin@ivanpupkinco.onmicrosoft.com",
 idp: "https://sts.windows.net/***/",
 altsecid: "***",
 sub: "***",
 given_name: "Ivan",
 family_name: "Pupkin-business",
 name: "TestAccount",
 amr: [
  "pwd"
 ],
 unique_name: "admin@ivanpupkinco.onmicrosoft.com",
 appid: "***",
 appidacr: "1",
 scp: "Calendars.ReadWrite Contacts.ReadWrite",
 acr: "1"
}.
[signature]`

Comment: multi-tenant app, authorize and token urls like `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/authorize?api-version=1.0`, trying to access `https://outlook.office365.com/` with third-party user credentials. It fails in multi-tenancy - just for this test user. API is working for users in AD where app located

Comment: Ok. There are some fields missing in the JWT, namely oid, upn, and puid. Did this user sign in with their Microsoft account (like an *@live.com, *@Hotmail.com, etc?) They need to sign in using the admin@ivanpupkinco.onmicrosoft.com username and corresponding password.

Comment: User is signed in, I double checked it - how could i obtain the token without signed user?

Comment: Right. However, some users link a Microsoft account(MSA) to their Office 365 account, then use the MSA to login. This doesn't work for Azure tokens (yet), so if they sign in with a linked MSA you'll get an error. What I was asking was if this user signed in using the *.onmicrosoft.com address or using a linked account.

Comment: yes, user signed in using *.onmicrosoft.com account. Maybe my trial account doesn't have active outlook/exchange subsription?  output of `Get-MsolServicePrincipal -AppPrincipalId 00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000` - `AccountEnabled        : False`

Comment: That was my next question. It looks like it doesn't from that output. You could try logging into Outlook Web App with the account to verify.

Comment: I've created new trial account with exchange subscription, now I can use outlook.office365.com web app, but my access token still doesn't have `oid, upn, puid` fields when i parse it - and, as as result, 401 error when i try to access API. What else can I check?

Comment: finnally got it working - the problem was in incorrect login url

Comment: Oh I see! What URL were you using that returned the token with missing fields?

Comment: :site => 'https://outlook.office365.com/',
  :authorize_url => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<app_id>/oauth2/authorize?api-version=1.0',
  :token_url => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<app_id>/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0'